# Update Element at every 10th Second, i.e., like at 12:30:10, 12:31:10, etc

Tags: javascript

**The question:** How to update element at every 10th Second, i.e., like at 12:30:10, 12:31:10, etc

The following technically works and does as I need, but how am I supposed to do this in the right way?  That is, optimally, in terms of code and execution time?

```
  setInterval(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    if (now.getSeconds() == 10) {
       $('#jama').load('jama.php');
    }
  },1000);
```

Comment: How exact you need it to be? Why every 10th second? You could get current seconds (e.g. 48), set timer to the next 10th second (70 - 48 = 22) and then start a minute timer which would call the load function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Problem**: I think what you're asking is: To check every for every tenth second, i.e., 12:30:10 is a *tenth second*, but check every ten seconds (12:30:13, 12:30:23, etc.) is not.

**The Solution**: In that case, use [**`setTimeout()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout), running it every second, to find the tenth second, and when you find the tenth second, then just [**`setInterval()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) as you're doing now.

**The Advantage**: What's the advantage?  Once you find the tenth second, you can change `setInterval()`'s delay from `1000` to `60000`, since we know the next tenth second will be 60 seconds away.  This reduces how often the code needs to check, and it also removes the `now()` object and the unnecessary checking.

**The Code**: Working demo below.

```js
var myinterval = false;

function findTenthSecond() {
  if(!myinterval) {
    findTenthSecond_async();
  }
}

function findTenthSecond_async() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    var now = new Date();
    console.log("Check second: " + now.getSeconds() + "|");
    if (now.getSeconds() == 10) {
      myinterval = true;

          // your code is here
      setInterval(function(){
        console.log ("Load jama.php");
        $('#jama').load('jama.php');
      },60000);  // updated the second count to 60 seconds

    } else {
      findTenthSecond();
    }    
  }, 1000);
}

findTenthSecond();
```

Comment: first sorry for wording my question wrong and then big thank you for the answer. It was exactly what I was looking for and also you mention exactly those things that made my solution felt clumsy

Comment: @StonieMalony Thanks!  No problem, feel free to mark this answer as "correct" (the checkmark) if it helped, so it can help others.